# Which SMS service API for inbound messages of more than 160 characters

Tags: php, sms, twilio, vonage

I have used Nexmo and Twilio for outbound and inbound messages. but none of them supporting more than 160 characters in inbound message for all carrier in US and Canada.

Please let me know if any sms service provider giving the inbound message(more than 160 chars) in all Carrier.

Comment: How about sending concatenated messages?

Comment: Yes I tried to concat the message into single message but not getting any identity to check the sequence of message.

Comment: In Twilio, you get the count at the top of the messages like (1/4) , (2/4) and so on... this works for major major US/Canada carriers except for Sprint.

Comment: Yes true, but I need for Sprint.

Comment: As it is specified in the documentation, that you can't send the message over 160 chars, I would suggest you to add custom pagination thing in your message body, by checking if the length in more than 160 chars. Definately, you would need to do it for Sprint.

Comment: Then How Skipio is working.
https://skipio.com/